# Delete Host information from Elasticsearch

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat

I upload some logs into elastic via filebeat, but there is some other information added to my original logs like the host name ,os kernel and other information about host..., and the main message become unformatted, i want to delete all the field that are unnecessary and only keep my original message in the initial form.

I have tried to delete `add_host_metadata` from filebeat.yml but the problem still persist.

I'm working with elk on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the include_fields processor [enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/include-fields.html) or what you could do is use the drop_fields for the fields you don’t need. Filebeat will sometimes add in fields such as host, or log, which can be dropped. There are some
That can’t be dropped though.

Comment: Thanks, I looked in this documentation but i don't know where to write processor I'm new with elastic.

Comment: You could add this to the filebeat.yml file in the Filebeat configuration, so that it is done before it gets sent to Elastic. This would then get the work done in Filebeat, so no elastic actions are required once ingested.